Do old inserts get treated as new CDC events during node bootstrap?
When a new Cassandra node bootstraps and receives data from existing tables for which Change Data Capture (CDC) is enabled, do old inserts get treated as new CDC events?  I don't see any reference to this behavior in the documentation for the Debezium Kafka connector, nor anything describing a connection between Cassandra's commitlog files and its cdc_raw directory during the bootstrap phase.  I expect, but cannot confirm without digging into Cassandra internals, that streamed data doesn't end up in cdc_raw/.

When a node is bootstrapping, parts of SSTables are streamed to it from other replicas. In other words, the range partitions in the SSTables whose partition keys map to token ranges are transferred to the joining node.
The replicas are not streaming the data as reconstructed mutations of INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements but actual fragments of the SSTables on disk.
By definition, CDC only captures data which has changed -- not the data which already exists on disk -- so only new writes will ever make it to the CDC flow. Cheers!
